# Second identical jest test failing after the first one passes

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have two identical jest tests, the first one passes and the second fails. From what I have read it could be something to do with mocking the `someFunction`. I am clearing all the mocks before each test, I have tried `jest.resetAllMocks();` but that does not seem to work.

```
const authenticatedUser = {
    "id": 1,
    "accessFlags": [],
}

jest.mock("../src/someFunction", () => ({
  return {someData: ["a", "b"]}
}));

describe("My Tests", () => {
  let ex;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();

    ex = new FauxExpress();
  });

  it("Description", async () => {
    const req = {
      user: { ...authenticatedUser, access: ["admin"] },
    };

    await doSomethingUsingMockedSomeFunction(req, ex.res);

    expect(ex.res.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });

  it("Description", async () => {
    const req = {
      user: { ...authenticatedUser, access: ["admin"] },
    };

    await doSomethingUsingMockedSomeFunction(req, ex.res);

    expect(ex.res.statusCode).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

Comment: does `authenticatedUser` variable has nested arrays or objects?

Comment: I have edited the code to include ```authenticatedUser```

Comment: does `authenticatedUser.accessFlags` get changed by `doSomethingUsingMockedSomeFunction`?

Comment: @OamarKanji you need to change the description of second test. You can't have two identical test description. And please always write descriptive meaningful description about your test cases. If that solve your concern I'll write the answer.

Comment: @MicaelLevi I don't think so but I'll double-check, thanks

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik thanks I did not know that, I have changed the description and some function names for this post as I do not want to publicly share the actual code since it is not open source.